# Getting compilation error while replacing a string

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I've created a Url Encoder class whose job is to encode or decode an Url.

For storing the special characters I've use a map `std::map<std::string, std::string> reserved`.

And I've initialized the map like this `this->reserved["!"] = ":)";`

For reading characters form a given string I'm using  an iterator`for(string::iterator it=input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it)`

Now when I try to replace a special character using replace function `encodeUrl.replace(position, 1, this->reserved[*it]);`

I get the following error

> Url.cpp: In member function ‘std::string Url::Url::UrlEncode(std::string)’:
>   Url.cpp:69:54: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]’ [-fpermissive]

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. Here's my function

```
string Url::UrlEncode(string input){

    short position = 0;
    string encodeUrl = input;

    for(string::iterator it=input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it){

        unsigned found = this->reservedChars.find(*it);

        if(found != string::npos){

            encodeUrl.replace(position, 1, this->reserved[*it]);
        }

        position++;

    }

    return encodeUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error in your solution is that you are trying to pass a single character rather than `std::string` or c-style 0-terminated string (`const char *`) to map.

`std::string::iterator` is iterating one char at a time, so you may want to use `std::map< char, std::string >`.

Answer (score 1):

`it` is an iterator of characters (it has type `std::string::iterator`). Thus, `*it` is a character.

You are doing `reserved[*it]`, and because of the type you gave to `reserved` (`std::map<std::string, std::string>`), the subscript operator expects a `string`, not a `char`.

The compiler then tries a user-defined conversion from `char` to `std::string`, but there is no constructor of `string` which accepts a `char`. There is one that accepts a `char const*` though (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)), but the compiler can't convert a `char` to a `char const*`; hence, the error.

Also notice, that you should not use `unsigned` for the value returned by `string::find()`, but rather `string::size_type`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a mismatch between the type of *it and what

```
 reservedChars.find()
```

is supposed to accept.

Try adding

```
const char* pit = *it;
```

right before

```
unsigned found = this->reservedChars.find(*pit);

    if(found != string::npos){

        encodeUrl.replace(position, 1, this->reserved[*pit]);
```